# How to make files placed in vagrantfile directory show up in VM

Tags: macos, vagrant

I'm having a lot of trouble transferring files to my VM. I tried vagrant scp but I couldn't get it to work. I also tried using github which isn't a very elegant solution but it does work. I would like to place files in my vagrantfile directory and have them show up in my VM but that's not working. I tried vagrant reload but still they won't show up in VM. How do I configure files to show up in VM when placed in vagrantfile directory? I'm using mac osx with ubuntu/trusty32 vm. Update: I got it to work by adding this to the vagrantfile

```
   config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"
```

where src/ is the home directory i want to share and /srv/website is the vm directory i want to share to. then i exited out of my vm and used

```
vagrant reload
```

and then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vagrant sync folder](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/) is I think the best and simplest way to achieve this.

By default you have the directory where you have `Vagrantfile` mapped with `/vagrant` directory within the VM. so any files you create there will automatically be pushed into this `/vagrant` VM directory

You can also synchronize any other directory - if you concern about VM performance issue, you can use `nfs` type to speed up transfer

```
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website", type: "nfs"
```

In this example any files from your `src/` folder within the vagrant project will be synchronized to the `/srv/website` folder of the VM and the files will be transferred using nfs type